# Shotwell/Code: Skript to remove RAW's of deleted jpg's

Tags: command-line, scripts, shotwell

When I import a nef file (say, x.nef), shotwell automatically converts it to a jpg, naming it x_nef_shotwell.jpg. However, when I delete a picture in shotwell, it only removes the jpg-file and not the NEF. The next time I start shotwell, it reimports the NEF and generates another JPG. I think that problem can be solved easily with a script that checks whether a NEF has a corresponding JPG of the described form and if that isn't case, deletes it. I don't really know how to approach this, could you please help me?

Thanks a lot,
Minamoto

Comment: This is a great idea but it would probably be best to file it with [Yorba's bug tracker as a feature request](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/issues?set_filter=1&tracker_id=2). If it is accepted and the issue fixed, it helps more people.

Comment: There's already an [open ticket on this issue](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4207).  Rather than writing a script, it would be preferable if Shotwell didn't have this bug in the first place.